# Как побороть CORS. Ибо вообще не понимаю, что делать?

Tags: javascript, cors

Прошу сильно не ругать, я пока совсем джун.

Проблема следующая:

Есть несколько запущенных локальных серверов на ***ноде(express.js)*** на удаленных компах, раскиданных по России, эти сервера мониторят за некоторыми процессами, данные для которых берут с другого локального сервера по протоколу OPC_UA. Эти локальные сервера открыты для внешнего мира через пакет "localtunnel". То есть с помощью этого пакета я получаю глобальную конечную точку по адресу **"https://example.loca.lt"**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот у меня этих конечных точек может быть много, до нескольких десятков.

Я их пытаюсь использовать следующим образом - примерно в интервале раз в 1-5 минут я делаю GET запрос с помощью "fetch" для каждой точки, но я не получаю данные, хоть и в консоли показывает статус 200.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изначально вообще блокировало политикой CORS, после чего я отключил его с помощью передачи параметра {mode:'no-cors'} в "fetch" запрос, но в консоли приходит ошибка ***"Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"***, хоть и в заголовках все равно приходит статус 200. Так же после установил Referrer в "no-referrer-when-downgrade", но результат тот же.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема? Как можно ее решить или в какую сторону нужно копать?

**P.S.** Что самое интересное, тот же код, нормально работает в Electron.js, так же все норм приходит в Постмане и при вставке ссылки в поисковую строку браузера.

Comment: Чудес на свете не бывает... Если работает в браузере, Electron.js и Postman, то сравните то, что отсылаете Вы и то, что отсылает работающий код/программа/браузер.

Comment: @XelaNimed Возможно я вас не совсем понимаю, но я делаю обычный GET запрос через fetch API. Я тут подумал, что возможно как то влияет webpack, но сделав точно такой же запрос с помощью fetch API прямо в консоли браузера я получаю ту же проблему, то есть webpack скорее всего не причем.

Comment: Приведите не работающий код. Что находится в файле wellsRendering.js на 32 строке? Ну и пишет, что ошибка в синтаксисе... Может в эту сторону копать?

Comment: Использую `localtunnel` вёрстку на мобилке потестить, когда локально проекты развернуты, не более. Думаю он для этого и был придуман)

Comment: @De.Minov, возможно )), есть платная альтернатива ngrok, но из-за санкций проблематично оплатить подписку ((

Answer (score 0):

В итоге:

Более подробно прочитал про CORS и понял в чем заключалась проблема.

***В результате исследования этого вопроса я пришел к следующему заключению:***

Проблема оказалась не в моем коде, мой **GET** запрос работает так как и должен он работать, фактически запрос выполняется и фактически приходит ответ, а нет результата из-за того, что этот ответ блокирует браузер согласно политики **CORS**, а вот в **Postman** и **Electron JS** все норм работает, в **Postman** понятно, что нет никакой политики, а вот в **Electron JS** скорее всего упрощенная версия политики и настраивается она через конфигурацию.

Решением является - установка на сервере **localtunnel** необходимых заголовков. Для этого необходимо сервер **localtunnel** развернуть у себя на хостинге со своими настройками и заголовками.

**P.S.** Почитав некоторую информацию на GitHub, я понял что бесплатный сервер **localtunnel**, развернутый на машине разработчика этого пакета, крайне не стабильный, с чем я сам часто сталкиваюсь, ссылки ежедневно неработоспособны какое-то время, видимо когда большие нагрузки. В принципе идеальной работы от него требовать не стоит, так как он бесплатный о чем говорит и сам разработчик, так же он говорит, что это не приоритетный проект для него и он к нему возвращается время от времени если есть желание и время.